# Relicensing from GPLv3 to GPLv2

Tags: gpl-3, github, relicensing, gpl-2, pull-request

I have an open source project on GitHub released under GPL3. I want to re-license it under GPL2. 99.9% of the program is written by me, only few lines of code is written by other people.

Can I re-license it again under GPL2? I mean, when someone sends me a pull request via GitHub, what is the "official agreement" between us on the issue?

Comment: If there are just a handful of lines by other people then the easiest thing to do is to explicitly ask them all for permission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since others have written code for the project, I believe they also have a small claim in the copyright of the project as a whole. Without a consensus of all copyright holders, I don't believe you are allowed to change the license of the project to GPLv2 because it is not compatible with GPLv3. However, if the other developers  signed a contributor license agreement (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contributor_License_Agreement and https://cla.github.com/), assigning the copyright to you, then you should be allowed to re-license.

Answer (score 3):

When receiving contributions to a project, the default assumption is that the contribution is under the same licence as the project itself.

The main exceptions are when the contribution explicitly mentions a different licence or if it is of such a trivial/mechanical nature that the contribution doesn't qualify for copyright protection. The last reason will apply only very rarely.

---

As you have accepted contributions to your project, you don't own all the copyrights and you can't change the license without explicit permission from the other contributers to the project.